# Import large files from S3 to RDS Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, psycopg2

I'm trying to set up a step in an application that a user selects files in an S3 bucket to import to a postgres RDS instance.

Currently my process is:

1. Copy a csv from S3 to EC2
2. Read a sample of the file with python pandas [read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html)
3. Create a 'CREATE TABLE' statement dynamically from what the pandas dataframe and execute it (with user input allowed)
4. \copy the file from EC2 to the RDS table using psycopg2 [copy_expert](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#cursor.copy_expert)

The trouble is, the files can be hundreds of GBs in size, and the EC2 instance I'm using only has a 50GB volume. I'd like a set up that bypasses the need to use EC2 as an intermediate step.

My ideal would be:

1. Read a sample of the file from S3 with pandas read_csv.
2. Create a 'CREATE TABLE' statement dynamically and execute it
3. \copy the file directly from S3 to RDS

But I'm hitting the following issues-

1. Pandas read_csv works with files on S3, but only if they're public, which is a bit of a security risk. I could temporarily make files public, but that seems like a bad idea.
2. \copy statements from S3 seem to be possible to import data from S3 to Redshift, but not from S3 to RDS.

Are there any ways around these two issues, or are there any cleaner solutions?